# How to calculate time complexity with variable list elements?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I got a really long time complexity for this function, not sure if we can simplify it.

```
# Let n = # of file names in the input
# Overall Time Complexity: O(n + k_0 + k_1 + k_2 + ... + k_n + 1) = O(n + k_0 + k_1 + k_2 + ... + k_n)
def split_input(input):

    # Time Complexity: O(n)
    file_names = input.split(",")

    # Let k_i = file name length for the i^th element
    # Time Complexity: O(k_0 + k_1 + k_2 + ... + k_n)
    for index, value in enumerate(file_names):
        # O(k_i)
        file_names[index] = file_names[index].strip()

    # Time Complexity: O(1)
    return file_names
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already defined *n* here as the total length of your `input` string, which includes all your file names, so

*n > k_0 + k_1 + ... + k_n*.

Therefore, your time complexity is just *O(n)*.

Comment: So we define "n" as the # of characters in the string rather than the # of actual file names in the string? e.g. "abc.csv, def.csv, ghi.csv"

Comment: @NoName Well you already claim that `input.split(",")` is *O(n)* so clearly you have chosen the total length of the string as your *n*, right? `str.split()` does have to go through all characters of the string.

Comment: If you prefer to define *n* as your number of file names, then your time complexity would be *O(k0 + k1 + ... + kn))* just *O(n * k_avg)* where *k_avg* is your average file name length. Can also express it as *O(n * k_longest)*, though that might be a less tight bound.